# VS2010 (C#) Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles is where in the Solution Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I have created a C# WinForms application.  It has some additional files that it uses, such as help files and some external data files.  I want to put these files in folders under the `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)` path so that the application can find and read them.

This path doesn't get created until the application is installed right?  So where do I put these files in my VS2010 project, or how do I tell my project that these files exist so that when I am running (debugging) the application from VS it will find the files.

Thanks

**EDIT:**  I did think about adding the files as resource files, but unfortunately some files may get added after the project is built and deployed. Therefore we decided to make the program search and find the data files (and associated help files) at a specific location and load them if they exist.

Comment: It's not the right place to put that files! They should stay in the application folder (if they're immutable. Get with Application.StartupPath) or the application data directory (if they may change over time).

Comment: The title of this question is not very clear. However I think the OP need to read only some help file or data file during debug as if it were a real deployment scenario thus assuming the current debug directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thing is that your application should not need to use 'Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles'. It "should" be location agnostic. The quick answer to your question is "from the folder that the application was launched from". The real answer is how you reference these files.

Your help files and data files need to be deployed to folder with a known relationship to the application. That is, the same folder or a child folder. Consider making the file resources.

Now if the files are user configurable or run time writable then they should not be in the program files area but be in the application data area. If so, then there is your path!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Rob, so I should reference the files using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)` and then I should manually add the files the folder C:\ProgramData\<myapp>, is that right?

Comment: Hi Ben ... yes you got it. Add yourself a subfolder to that path though. I always use <Company>/<App> ... have a look at the folders already there (if any).

Answer (score 1):

You should add these files to the main (exe) project inside your solution.
(Right click on Project Name, Select Add Existing Item)

Then set its property `Copy to Output Directory = Always`

(not sure of the translation because I use a localized version of VS)

Of course, it should be noted that, when you deploy your files in the `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles`, you could not be able to write to them (Windows7, Vista) for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks Steve, it turns out that I perhaps should be using the Common Application Data folder, but you provided an interesting alternative using the `Copy To Output Directory` property (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Add the files as resources in your project.  Take a look at this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  You can add resources to a project by right-clicking the Properties node under your project in Solution Explorer, clicking Open, and then clicking the Add Resource button on the Resources page in Project Designer.

You can add resources to your project either as linked resources, which are external files, or as embedded resources, which are embedded directly into the .resx file.

When you add a linked resource, the .resx file that stores your project resource information includes only a relative path to the resource file on disk. If you add images, videos, or other complex files as linked resources, you can edit them using a default editor that you associate with that file type in the Resource Designer.

When you add an embedded resource, the data is stored directly in the project's resource (.resx) file. Strings can only be stored as embedded resources.

[image: Adding a resource in Visual Studio]

Comment: Thanks Emmie, I did think about adding the files as resource files, but unfortunately some files may get added after the project is built and deployed.  Therefore we decided to make the program search and find the data files at a specific location and load them if they exist.